# How do I Implement Infinity scroll plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this plugin to implement the Infinity scroll plugin: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Below is my code which is going to handle the infinite scroll:

```
 <ul class="pager">
<li class="current"><a href="#"><b>1</b></a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/freegames//cat/0/all/newest/p2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/freegames//cat/0/all/newest/p3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/freegames//cat/0/all/newest/p4">4</a></li>
<li><a rel="next" href="http://localhost/freegames//cat/0/all/newest/p2">»</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Below is my script:

```
 <script>
 function infiniteScroller() {
  $('.homecont').infinitescroll({

navSelector  : "ul.pager li.current a",            
               // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : "ul.pager li a[rel~="next"]",    
               // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : "div.ig"          
               // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    });
}
  </script>
```

When I load the page it doesn't work. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually call your `infiniteScroller()` function?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
        infiniteScroller();
    });

Ok I added this. But still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, your `navSelector` should be the entire nav, not just the first element:

```
navSelector  : "ul.pager",
```

Your `nextSelector` here is invalid. You can't use double-quotes inside of double quotes, and the `~=` is unnecessary for your sample HTML.

```
nextSelector : "ul.pager li a[rel='next']",
```

Comment: Thanks bro! :) It actually worked. But it is not fetching the blocks of the next page to the current page.

Comment: I don't have enough of your code to help you further. Try reading the documentation more carefully; it should have everything that you need.

Comment: Bro! I finally did it :) Thanks for your big help. I was feeling down all this time!